# Parent view is not displayed after the low memory warning is received during MFMailCompose modal is open, canceled and draft saved/deleted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, memory-management, didreceivememorywarning

I have the following structure on my iPhone app

AppDelegate / UITabBarController / 5 UINavigationControllers(My tabs) / UIViewController(like rootViewController for each UINavigationController)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    HomeViewController *homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    GoalsTableViewController *goalsTableViewController = [[GoalsTableViewController alloc] init];
    HistoryViewController *historyViewController = [[HistoryViewController alloc] init];
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

    self.navBarActivity = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];

    self.navBarSettings = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsViewController];

    self.navBarHistory = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:historyViewController];

    self.navBarGoals = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:goalsTableViewController];

    self.navBarAbout = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:infoViewController];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.navBarActivity, self.navBarGoals, self.navBarHistory,self.navBarSettings, self.navBarAbout, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController =  self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}
```

In some UIViewControllers I implemented a MFMailComposeViewController in order to send emails.

I experimented a weird issue (reproduced on simulator and real devices iOS 5.0 and 5.1)...

Using an iPhone Simulator (only iOS 5.0 or 5.1), if I simulate a low memory warning while a MFMailComposerViewController modal is open on the screen and then tap on Cancel and then tap on Delete|Save draft, when the modal is dismissed the parent view seems not visible (blanked view).

The life cycle seems work fine due, if I follow the same steps but after simulate a low memory warning I send the email from MFMailComposeViewController modal, when modal is dismissed, my parent view looks fine.

Any suggestions how to prevent my parent view from being unloaded on memory warning?

---

Edit1

I figured out what is happening, after unloading and comeback to the view and entering the last view within viewdidload(life cycle), the tabBar is not inserting navigation view. I check the subviews of tabBar:

```
UITransitionView
   ==><UIViewControllerWrapperView>
       ==> empty
<UITabBar>
```

I reintegrated the view of navigationBar by adding as subview in viewdidload:

```
    UIView *tabBarControllerWrapperView = [[[self.tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

    // tabBar UIViewControllerWrapperView has not views
    if([tabBarControllerWrapperView.subviews count] == 0)
    {
         // add navigationbar view
         [tabBarControllerWrapperView addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    }
```

There is no better way to fix it, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After a memory warning is possible that on the non visible controllers is called viewDidUnload (iOS <= 5 ).In your case the view of the controller that presented the modal mailcomposer was probably unloaded.

The idea behind viewDidUnload is that you save the data you need to restore the view once viewDidLoad is called again. What you have to keep in mind is that your viewDidLoad can be called multiple times.

On iOS6 viewDidUnload is not called anymore, so this logic must be moved to didReceiveMemoryWarning

Comment: Thanks @elio.d, But we reviewed the life cycle and is working fine, also in others modal like ad banners, but with email composer was unexpected because is entering in viewdidload and reconstruct all their view objects but is not inserting into the view. We figured out that tabbar is not inserting navigation bar view, but is totally weird.